# Constant value properties

Tags: c#, constants

Will non-virtual properties to constant values be evaluated in compile time? (Like the constants themselves)

Example:

```
class Clazz
{
    const int SPEED = 5;

    public int Speed 
    {
    get { return SPEED; }
    }
}
```

I know that any call to the constant `SPEED` will be evaluated once at compile time, but if I access the `Clazz.Speed` *property* from anywhere in my program, will that also be evaluated at **compile time**?

**Edit:** To evlove the question a little bit, will the next two examples be inlined by the **Compiler** (and not the JIT)? [ie. evaluated during compile time] :

```
// a static / non-static method that returns a constant value
(static) int GetConstant() { return 42; }

// a static / non-static property that returns a constant value
(static) int ConstProperty { get { return 42; } }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What problem are you having that this matters?

Comment: @M.Babcock to be honest there is no specific problem that this addresses, simply a thought that came to me. I was surprised when I couldn't easily find an answer to this on the web.

Comment: This would probably be a better fit for the format of http://programmers.stackexchange.com. Theoretical, *what happens in the compiler and why* type questions are slightly out of the scope of SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running this through Linqpad produces the following IL for the getter:

```
Clazz.get_Speed:
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.5  //push integer value 5 on evaluation stack   
IL_0001:  ret
```

This would mean that the getter is called at runtime (and not inlined) and returns a constant value.

Hypothetically if the getter would be inlined in this case that would mean that the implementation of the property could not be changed without having to recompile any consuming assemblies - this would defeat using a property in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not be evaluated at compile time, but it may be inlined at run-time.

Comment: what prevents the *compiler* from inlining non-virtual methods that return constant values?

Comment: @Acidic, if it's in another assembly, then you could switch that one without recompiling, and the behavior has to change.

Comment: @svick Is there any way I can force the compiler to inline that?

Comment: @Acidic, yes, use the `const` field directly. If you don't do that, you're telling the compile you don't want to inline the value.

Answer (score 1):

No, Property will not be evaluated at compile time.

Actually this is the one benefit of using Property.

Take your code for example:

```
class Clazz
{
    public const int SPEED = 5;

    public int Speed 
    {
    get { return SPEED; }
    }
}
```

If you use Clazz.SPEED in another assembly which will be evaluated at compile time. you have to deploy 2 assembly if you change the value of SPEED.

If you use Clazz.Speed, you only need to deploy the one assembly in that Clazz resides.

Alternative is using readonly static member variable. but Property is recommended which is flexible to extend.

Please read The first 2 Items of book: Effective C#: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your C#
Item1: Always use Properties Instead of Accessible Data Members
Item2: Prefer readonly to const